# How to perform a search in a custom website and read results?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am developing a function to download protein .pdb files online as part of a body of code I am creating to dock protein and ligands generated by our AIBind machine learning model. For around 60% of these proteins I am able to use gene libraries to convert their HGNC IDs to pdb IDs, which I then query through the website uniprot and RCSB to download pdb files. However, for the other 40% there only exist computationally generated alphafold PDB models for the proteins, and the gene libraries I have been using do not recognize these proteins as having valid PDB IDs. Thankfully, there is a search function on the alphafold website, where by searching with the HGNC ID, I recieve a list of entries (where the top one is 99% the protein I am looking for), as shown below;

[image]

Once I have the uniprot ID (which is shown in this example as Q7K0E6), I can then navigate to the alphafold entry page and access the file server to download the PDB file for that protein, which I have already been able to successfully perform for proteins that have a registered uniprot ID in the databanks that I have been utilizing.

I've been using the following code to scrape the search webpage with the HGNC symbol inputted as a search entry, putting all of the HTML page data into a text file.

```
  import urllib
  import urllib.request
  import requests

  url = 'https://alphafold.ebi.ac.uk/search/text/'
  fname = 'alphaname.txt'
  HGNC = 'vr1'
  url = url + 'vr1'

  get = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  html = get.read()
  r = requests.get(url)
  with open(fname, "wb") as f:
       f.write(html)
```

When I perform a search in the file itself (manual as well as through python), I don't see any data from any of the entries queried as search results.

[image]

How would I use python to retrieve data from searches performed within the search function of a website?

Answer (score 1):

The data is loaded from external URL via JavaScript. You can use `requests` module to simulate it, for example:

```py
import json
import requests


api_url = "https://alphafold.ebi.ac.uk/api/search"

params = {
    "q": "(text:*vr1 OR text:vr1*)",
    "type": "main",
    "start": "0",
    "rows": "20",
}

data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "numFound": 112,
    "start": 0,
    "numFoundExact": true,
    "docs": [
        {
            "entryId": "AF-O35433-F1",
            "gene": "Trpv1",
            "geneT": [
                "Trpv1",
                "Vr1",
                "Vr1l"
            ],
            "geneSynonyms": [
                "Vr1",
                "Vr1l"
            ],
            "sequenceChecksum": "DAFC80B12BDF71BF",
            "sequenceVersionDate": "1998-01-01",
            "uniprotAccession": "O35433",
            "uniprotAccessionT": "O35433",
            "uniprotId": "TRPV1_RAT",
            "uniprotDescription": "Transient receptor potential cation channel subfamily V member 1",
            "protein": [
                "Transient receptor potential cation channel subfamily V member 1",
                "Capsaicin receptor",
                "Osm-9-like TRP channel 1",
                "Vanilloid receptor 1",
                "Vanilloid receptor type 1-like",
                "OTRPC1"
            ],
            "taxId": 10116,
            "organismScientificName": "Rattus norvegicus",
            "organism": [
                "Rattus norvegicus",
                "Rat"
            ],
            "globalMetricValue": 71.55,
            "uniprotStart": 1,
            "uniprotEnd": 838,
            "uniprotSequence": "MEQRASLDSEESESPPQENSCLDPPDRDPNCKPPPVKPHIFTTRSRTRLFGKGDSEEASPLDCPYEEGGLASCPIITVSSVLTIQRPGDGPASVRPSSQDSVSAGEKPPRLYDRRSIFDAVAQSNCQELESLLPFLQRSKKRLTDSEFKDPETGKTCLLKAMLNLHNGQNDTIALLLDVARKTDSLKQFVNASYTDSYYKGQTALHIAIERRNMTLVTLLVENGADVQAAANGDFFKKTKGRPGFYFGELPLSLAACTNQLAIVKFLLQNSWQPADISARDSVGNTVLHALVEVADNTVDNTKFVTSMYNEILILGAKLHPTLKLEEITNRKGLTPLALAASSGKIGVLAYILQREIHEPECRHLSRKFTEWAYGPVHSSLYDLSCIDTCEKNSVLEVIAYSSSETPNRHDMLLVEPLNRLLQDKWDRFVKRIFYFNFFVYCLYMIIFTAAAYYRPVEGLPPYKLKNTVGDYFRVTGEILSVSGGVYFFFRGIQYFLQRRPSLKSLFVDSYSEILFFVQSLFMLVSVVLYFSQRKEYVASMVFSLAMGWTNMLYYTRGFQQMGIYAVMIEKMILRDLCRFMFVYLVFLFGFSTAVVTLIEDGKNNSLPMESTPHKCRGSACKPGNSYNSLYSTCLELFKFTIGMGDLEFTENYDFKAVFIILLLAYVILTYILLLNMLIALMGETVNKIAQESKNIWKLQRAITILDTEKSFLKCMRKAFRSGKLLQVGFTPDGKDDYRWCFRVDEVNWTTWNTNVGIINEDPGNCEGVKRTLSFSLRSGRVSGRNWKNFALVPLLRDASTRDRHATQQEEVQLKHYTGSLKPEDAEVFKDSMVPGEK",
            "modelCreatedDate": "2021-07-01",
            "organismCommonNames": [
                "Rat"
            ],
            "proteinFullNames": [
                "Capsaicin receptor",
                "Osm-9-like TRP channel 1",
                "Vanilloid receptor 1",
                "Vanilloid receptor type 1-like"
            ],
            "proteinShortNames": [
                "OTRPC1"
            ],
            "latestVersion": 2,
            "allVersions": [
                1,
                2
            ],
            "_version_": 1723016518349881344
        },
        {
            "entryId": "AF-Q7K0E6-F1",
            "gene": "AspRS",
            "geneT": [

...
```